# Thread wrapper with custom destruct function

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

Let me start with a short example

```
class A
{
public:
  A() :
    thread_([this] {
      std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(mtx_);
      cv_.wait(lk, [this] { return quit_; });
    })
  {
    throw std::exception();
  }

  ~A()
  {
    quit_ = true;
    cv_.notify_one();
    thread_.join();
  }

private:
  bool quit_ = false;
  std::mutex mtx_;
  std::condition_variable cv_;
  std::thread thread_;
};

int main()
{
  try { A a; }
  catch (...) {}
  // Does not reach this point
}
```

Because an exception is thrown in the constructor, the members are being destructed in reverse order.
the thread_ member is still joinable so terminate is being called.

It is pretty straightforward to write a thread wrapper class with a customizable destructor.

For example, something like that:

```
class ThreadWrapper
{
public:
    ThreadWrapper(std::function<void(std::thread & t)> onDestruct, std::thread&& thread) :
        onDestruct_(onDestruct),
        thread_(std::move(thread))
    {
    }

    ~ThreadWrapper()
    {
        onDestruct_(thread_);
    }
private:
    std::function<void(std::thread & t)> onDestruct_;
    std::thread thread_;
};

class B
{
public:
    B() :
        thread_(
        [this](std::thread& t) {
            quit_ = true;
            cv_.notify_one();
            t.join();
        },
        std::thread([this] {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(mtx_);
            cv_.wait(lk, [this] { return quit_; });
        }))
    {
        throw std::exception();
    }

private:
    bool quit_ = false;
    std::mutex mtx_;
    std::condition_variable cv_;
    ThreadWrapper thread_;
};
```

However, I was surprised not to find something like that in the boost library.
The closest thing I found is the scoped_thread which lets you pass a specific action as a template parameter.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Why don't you make a destructor definition in your `ThreadWrapper` instead of passing `onDestruct_` function? I don't see any particular reason why this should be available as a part of boost. Check out my example of `std::thread` wrapper [here](https://github.com/m-peko/thread-utils/blob/master/utils/thread.hpp) and the example of its usage [here](https://github.com/m-peko/thread-utils/blob/master/examples/thread.cpp).

Comment: @NutCrackerBecause ThreaqdWrapper is meant to be a generic solution. Of course I can write a wrapper for every thread I create, but that not the point. Boost designers have already paid attention to this problem so they created the scoped_thread class. However, by not letting to pass an actual functor object they limited its ability.

Comment: But destructor for every thread should be the same. Specialize destructors of the classes that inherit from `ThreadWrapper` class.